# Regular expression for custom template - nesting (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, nested

I have problem with creating regular expressions for my own template engine. 
My code:

```
       $re_foreachelse = '%
        {foreach (.+?) as (.+?)}
        (
          [^{]*
          (?:
            {
            (?!/?foreach(.*?)})
            [^{]*
          )*
        )
        {foreachelse}
        (
          [^{]*
          (?:
            {
            (?!/?foreach(.*?)})
            [^{]*
          )*
        )
        {/foreach}
        %x';

        $re_foreach = '%
        {foreach (.+?) as (.+?)}
        (
          [^{]*
          (?:
            {
            (?!/?foreach(.*?)})
            [^{]*
          )*
        )
        {/foreach}
        %x';

        while(preg_match($re_foreachelse, $this->tpl)) $this->tpl = preg_replace($re_foreachelse, '[foreach $1 as $2]$3[foreachelse]$4[/foreach]', $this->tpl);
        while(preg_match($re_foreach, $this->tpl)) $this->tpl = preg_replace($re_foreach, '[foreach $1 as $2]$3[/foreach]', $this->tpl);
```

I will be generating php code, but for testing it only changes "{}" to "[]". My problem is, that this works for most of nested tags:

```
 [foreach $items as $item] $item [foreach $item as $i] $i [foreachelse][/foreach] $item [foreachelse][/foreach]
 {foreach $items as $item} [foreach $tests as $test] [foreach $test as $t] [/foreach] [/foreach] {foreachelse} {/foreach}
 [foreach $othertests as $test] [foreach $item as $i] $i [foreachelse][/foreach] [/foreach]
```

However, as you can see, one is not changed and still has "{}". It looks that nesting of foreach with foreachelse into foreach works, but doesn't the other way.

I'm just beginner in regular expressions and i really don't know where the problem is.
Thank you in advance for any good ideas.

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Doing this kind of work using only regexp is doomed to fail, you should use a lexer + parser. My advice: take a look at [Twig code](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig) ([lexer](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Lexer.php), [parser](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Parser.php))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a "foreach foreachelse" can be included in a simple "foreach" and vice-versa. So whatever the order you choose to make the two kinds of replacement, the problem stay the same.
An other thing, the `preg_match` tests are useless, If you want to stop the replacements when there are no more replacements to do, use the "count" parameter of `preg_replace` and use a `do...while` loop to test it.

So there are several solutions:

**use only one loop**:

```
$count1 = 0; $count2 = 0;
do {
    $this->tpl = preg_replace($re_foreachelse, '[foreach $1 as $2]$3[foreachelse]$4[/foreach]', $this->tpl, -1, $count1);
    $this->tpl = preg_replace($re_foreach, '[foreach $1 as $2]$3[/foreach]', $this->tpl, -1, $count2);
} while ($count1 || $count2);
```

*Note that writing two consecutive `preg_replace` can be shorten if you use an array of patterns and an array of replacements as parameters for a single `preg_replace` statement.*

**use only one pattern with `preg_replace_callback`**:

```
$re_foreachcommon = '%
    {foreach (.+?) as (.+?)}
    (
      [^{]*
      (?:
        {
        (?!/?foreach(.*?)})
        [^{]*
      )*
    )
    (?:
        {foreachelse}
        (
          [^{]*
          (?:
            {
            (?!/?foreach(.*?)})
            [^{]*
          )*
        )
    )?
    {/foreach}
    %x';

$count=0;
do {
    $this->tpl = preg_replace_callback($re_foreachcommon, function ($m) {
        return '[foreach ' .$m[1] . ' as ' . $m[2] . ']' . $m[3]
              . ($m[4] ? '[foreachelse]' . $m[4] : '') . '[/foreach]';
    }, $this->tpl, -1, $count);
} while ($count);
```

**The fastest way if it is possible**:

Most of the time you don't need to capture the content between markers in a template system, I will show you an example for the fake replacement you use in your question, but you can expand the same idea to your real case:

```
// you store in this array, all the tokens that only needs a simple replacement
$trans = array('{/foreach}' => '[/foreach]',
               '{foreachelse}' => '[foreachelse]',
               '{/foreachelse}' => '[/foreachelse]');

$this->tpl = strtr($this->tpl, $trans);

// after you only need to make more advanced replacements
$this->tpl = preg_replace('%{foreach (.+?) as (.+?)}%', '[foreach $1 as $2]', $this->tpl);
```

In this way you avoid the nesting problem and you parse your string only two times.